# Difference b/w Hibernate's Sessionfactory.getCurrentSession() and SessionFactory.openSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

I'm a little confused between the two. As per I know both returns hibernate session, `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` returns a contextual session based on the property `<property name="current_session_context_class">` which is set in hibernate.cfg.xml 
Shouldn't we always go with this approach?

What additional value is added by `SessionFactory.openSession()`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A session is opened whenever `sf.getCurrentSession()` is called for the first time. This creates a brand new session if one does not exist or uses an existing one if one already exists.

In Tomcat this associates a session with a thread which is created using the underlying `ThreadLocal` object. But since Tomcat uses thread pooling it is entirely possible that a request may receive a thread with a session already associated with it, thus introducing the possibility of not even creating a brand new session. Another thing is that The Session that you obtained with `sf.getCurrentSession()` is flushed and closed automatically.

The method `sf.openSession()` on the other hand creates a new session but does not attempt to associate it with a thread. But remember `sf.openSession()` introduces another hitch in that it expects users to handle the closing and flushing of sessions themselves, instead of letting Hibernate do it automatically for us.

`sf.getCurrentSession()` is usually sufficient. `sf.openSession()` provides and facilitates a greater level of management of where the session is stored and managed. It's certainly an advanced option.

Comment: Does that mean that if I am using sf.getCurrentSession for multithreads inside tomcat - it will use the same session? is it ok?